# How do I pull data from a K2 extra field that is an array?

Tags: cms, php, k2

I'm building a site that uses K2 extra fields, but I'm customizing the output so I'm not just pulling the entire extra field block.

Normally something like this works for single entry fields:

```
<?php if($this->item->extraFields->streetaddressone->value != ''): ?>
 <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue Address1"><?php echo $this->item->extraFields->streetaddressone->value ?></span>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

But I have a field that is a multi-select list and I want to pull the entire array into a line on my item page.

I'm a bit of a hack, so I just got stuck on this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on what .php document you're in - if you're in item.php, or the category-item.php files, the following should work.

In the top of the document, add this code:

```
<!-- Call to prepare extra fields --> 
<?php  
$extrafields = array();
foreach($this->item->extra_fields as $item)
{    
$extrafields[$item->id] = $item->value;
}   
?>
```

Then, wherever you'd like to call the value of the filled in field, use this:

```
<?php if($extrafields[ID_NUMBER_OF_FIELD]!=''):?> <!-- if filled in, then call data -->
<?php echo $extrafields[ID_NUMBER_OF_FIELD];?> <!-- actual data call -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

tag.php works a little differently, as does the K2 Modules.

tag.php - you don't need the extra code in the head, the following will call your field data.

```
<?php $extrafields = json_decode($item->extra_fields);?>
<?php foreach($extrafields as $key=>$value): ?>
<?php if($extrafields[$key]->id == 'ID_NUMBER_OF_FIELD'&&$extrafields[$key]->value!=''): ?>
<?php echo $extrafields[$key]->value; ?>,
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Again, with the module_k2_content, you don't need the top data call.  Get your field data this way:

```
<?php echo $item->extraFields->ALIAS_OF_FIELD->value ;?>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am in item.php and that totally worked. Thank you!

Comment: No problem!!! I spent many a hour figuring this out, glad it could help someone else.

Comment: FYI, that code was originally written for me by Jordan. He's on here too, he knows awesome stuff and makes things work for me when I look like I'm about to cry.
http://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/75/jordan-ramstad

Answer (score 2):

@reactionfaye 's reply above is correct. For reference, this has been part of K2 since Nov 2012 :)

Originally introduced in this blog post for the release of K2 v2.6.2 (http://getk2.org/blog/1068-k2-v262-now-available):

> So how would you directly output individual extra fields in your K2
>   overrides? Simple. Just do something like this (e.g. in item.php) to
>   get the extra field name:
>
> $this->item->extraFields->EXTRAFIELDALIASHERE->name
>
> To get the extra field value you would simply do this:
>
> $this->item->extraFields->EXTRAFIELDALIASHERE->value
>
> Now replace EXTRAFIELDALIASHERE with the actual alias of the extra
>   field you wish to output.

Answer (score -3):

This can be done with a language override now, Avoiding overwriting your hacks when you upgrade K2.
Look for the constant K2_DATE_FORMAT_LC