# How to create Multiple Sets of K2 Extra Fields for the same K2 item

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2

Take this scenario:

K2 Extra fields: from-date, to-date, tax-rate.

Now for any single K2 item there will be multiple sets of these extra fields.
But K2 item shows only 1 set of extra fields and no option to create its array.

While create a K2 item there is no option to create another set of the same extra fields for the same K2 item.

For example this is how i want (multiple sets of extra fields data for the K2 item)

```
from-date, to-date, tax-rate
2011 2012 4%
2012 2013 5%
2013 2014 5.5%
```

How can this be achieved? Any extension to K2 for some other way.

Comment: The answer you're seeking may possibly be here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/208/how-do-i-pull-data-from-a-k2-extra-field-that-is-an-array/210#210

Comment: well i already checked that and that post is about only 1 set of extra fields.

Comment: `foreach($extrafields)` << meaning the possibility of more than 1 ;)

Comment: Extra fields are stored in an Array. Now what i am talking about is an Array of Array of Extra Fields....

i want multiple **SETS** of the same extra fields...
e.g.
[{2011,2012,4},{2013,2014,5},{2014,2015,5.5}]

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Can you show an example of what the k2 extra fields would look like in the back end, and how you want it to be output?

Comment: Actually, we paid someone to build this exact thing.  It's the guy who makes this: http://www.joomreem.com/multiple-extra-fields-groups-mefg-for-k2.html Contact him and ask him about the K2 Data Sets plugin he built.

Answer (score 3):

I have just recently stumbled upon following extension http://www.joomreem.com/multiple-extra-fields-groups-mefg-for-k2.html . It is commercial, and they claim to solve just the problem of having multiple Extra Field Groups for a K2 item. Haven't tested it yet, though...

Answer (score 2):

We have added multiple extra fields for K2. Extra fields can be applied to multiple extra field groups. The extra field groups can then be applied to multiple items or users.

At test version can be download from

[Github download of k2 multiple extra fields](https://github.com/jameswadsworth/k2/releases)

**WARNING** - this is only for testing purposes. It should only by used on a test/development site.

Answer (score 2):

This exactly what the Datasets for K2 plugin does: http://www.joomreem.com/extensions-store/k2-datasets

Also, there is a documentation to learn in details how to use it: http://www.joomreem.com/documentation/item/58-joomreem-k2-datasets-user-manual.html

Comment: I concur. I commissioned the development of this plugin at my old place of employment because we needed rows of field sets on each K2 item. It works :)